# Text User Interface

Tags: shell-script, aix, text, user-interface

I have been working on a shell script, and was wondering if I can put up a text user interface for the shell script. After some searching, I see few people suggest using "ncurses/curses". However the OS I am in, AIX 6.1, does not have curses installed.

I want to achieve a window much like "topas" interface.

At this moment, I am working on using lot of tput commands to achieve a simpler looking window.

Is there a better option? Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve (I don't know what a "topas" interface is). There are doubtless a lot of tools and libraries available to help you achieve it but it sounds like you are not open to installing curses (why?) so I'm not sure if you are open to installing [anything else](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail) either.

Comment: I do not have curses/ncurses installled presently. Having them is lengthy process to followup with admins/paper work. If you have seen "topas" screen, it bring up bunch of items in a single screen compraising of columns, with individual column data getting refreshed.

Comment: You are unhappy with just using built-in tools like `tput` so you would like something fancier and more functional, but you do not want to install anything fancier or more functional because it "is lengthy process". You want to have your cake and eat it too!

Comment: When building basic UIs for command line tools, I tend to merely make copious use of `printf "\rnew stuff on line"` and merely make sure that the text is never long enough to wrap.  The `\r` goes to the beginning of the current line without going to a new line (which would be `\n`).  For a one of my scripts, I also use other sequences, like `\e[1A` to go up one line, but relative positioning must always be very careful to avoid wrapping.

Comment: That helps. Thanks for the suggestion. I want to put a small window with menu items, more like a terminal with menu items and ability to change the menus based on choices. What it appears to be is that, I need to come up entirely. `curses` and `ncurses` might help, but at this moment, nothing I can make use of.